# Supply mysql command in shell script

Tags: mysql, shell, automation, sh

I am trying to automate some tasks for mysql docker container for that I am using a shell script. But I not able to pass/supply mysql commands after starting mysql server.

Below is my shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql.server start
mysql -u root
show databases;
```

All steps are works as expected else last one 'show databases;' am not getting how to pass 'show databases;' command after mysql server starts. I am on a MAC machine, same behaviour happens on my ubuntu 14.04 container.

below is output on my console.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DBNAME -e 'show databases;'
```

USER is your user
PASSWORD is your password
-e switch is used to fire commands to mysql via shell

A sample output:

```
User@Host:~> mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD DBNAME -e 'show databases ;'
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mdpdb              |
| mdpdb6             |
| mysql              |
+--------------------+
```

Comment: what is DBNAME here

Comment: Here my DBNAME is "mdpdb". You can put your dbname.

Comment: please note: i didn't typeout the actual user,password,dbname here.